# How to upgrade an MSI that contains a deprecated component?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, wix3.10

We have a case where an older version of the product contained a component that is not shipped with the new version.  The problem we are having is two-fold... first, the services are not being stopped, leading to forced reboots.  Second, the files are not being removed.

Now, I am unsure if this is due to the authoring of the old installshield-built msi, or something I might not be doing properly in wix (using a custom bootstrapper around our msi).  I can upgrade current version of the product without issue, so I'm suspecting the former.

What I would like to achieve, is a workaround (not against using a custom action) to handle the case of upgrades, where, if a pre-version 7.x product is found, then I fire a CA to stop those services and remove those files.  How would I set out to achieve that?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what is wrong with the upgrade scenario. Do you have a component deprecated in the new setup that contains services that won't uninstall properly during your upgrade? Does the component contain multiple files? If so what files?